# Reversing a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I've tried reading everywhere, and can't seem to find the answer that works...
The exercise is to create a function that takes a number (`0-6`) and returns the corresponding day of the week, with Sunday numbered as `0`.  I did that using a dictionary.  Now it wants the other way around, but everything I've tried doesn't seem to work except typing it in.  Here's my current code started for reverse:

```
dayDict = {0: 'Sunday', 1:'Monday', 2:'Tuesday', 3:'Wednesday',
           4:'Thursday', 5:'Friday', 6:'Saturday'}


def day_num(dayName):
    if dayName == "Sunday":
        return dayDict[dayName]

print(day_num("Sunday"))
```

It would continue with an `elif` for each day.

Comment: Yes, that is obvious. However, I'd like to know to reverse it for my own knowledge

Comment: `{v:k for k,v in dayDict.items()}`?

Comment: `dayDict` should've been a `list` in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what it sounds like, you want a new function that takes in Sunday-Saturday and returns the corresponding numerical value.

The only method I can think of to do this is to use a loop and test all of the dictionary options like so:

```
def getDayNumber(day):
   for i in range(len(<dictionary>)):
       if <dictionary>[i] == day.captialize():
           return i
```

Comment: This is a terribly inefficient approach. It's best to make a new dictionary like @Prune did.

Comment: @pzp I know but he said he didn't want to make a new dictionary.

Comment: This actually worked the way I was hoping to do.  Is there any particular reason it is inefficient @pzp?  I'm like a month into this, so bear with me.

Comment: The reason I said it was inefficient was because each time it needs to lookup a day number, it has to potentially cycle through all of the days and use a dictionary lookup to get the values. That means that in the worst case scenario, the code has to do seven dictionary lookups while most of the other answers require only one lookup. In practice, this is probably not even noticeable though, so if it works and this is what you were hoping to do, go ahead and use it (and maybe give this the best answer checkmark).

Answer (score 2):

A reverse dictionary is a simple line of code ... once you know how.

```
day_num = {value: key for key, value in dayDict.iteritems()}
```

Comment: Correct in this case where there is a one-to-one mapping of the keys to values.  Of course it is not possible to correctly "reverse" a dictionary where the new keys would overlap.  d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}, d2 = {1: 'a', 2: 'b'} or {1: 'c', 2: 'b'} depending on the random order it gets assigned when reversed.

Answer (score 1):

```
dayNumDict = {v:k for k,v in dayDict.iteritems()}
def day_num(dayName):
    return dayNumDict[dayName]
```

If you are using Python 3.x:

```
dayNumDict = {v:k for k,v in dayDict.items()}
def day_num(dayName):
    return dayNumDict[dayName]
```

Comment: I've seen this, and tried it.  I keep getting:
'dict' object has not attribute 'iteritems'

Lost on that part...sorry, fairly new!

Comment: It looks like you are using Python 3.x. Try dayDict.items() instead of dayDict.iteritems()

Comment: getting KeyError 'Sunday' now

Comment: How do you call the function? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

you can also built your dict with both the day and the number in it, like this

```
>>> days=['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday', 'Wednesday','Thursday','Friday', 'Saturday']
>>> dayDict=dict()
>>> for n,day in enumerate(days):
        dayDict[n]=day
        dayDict[day]=n


>>> dayDict
{0: 'Sunday', 1: 'Monday', 2: 'Tuesday', 3: 'Wednesday', 4: 'Thursday', 5: 'Friday', 6: 'Saturday', 
'Tuesday': 2, 'Thursday': 4, 'Friday': 5, 'Wednesday': 3, 'Saturday': 6, 'Sunday': 0, 'Monday': 1}
>>> 
>>> dayDict[0]
'Sunday'
>>> dayDict["Friday"]
5
>>>
```

Comment: This makes sense.  I thought of doing this, but I figured there just had to be a way to reverse the dictionary I had already created for the first function.   I'm fairly new to programming (bout a month in), so I'm never sure if my more simple solution of just re-doing it is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already got a bunch of dictionary answers.... In your specific case it seems like this would be easier-solved with an Enum.

```
from enum import IntEnum

DOW = IntEnum("DOW", "Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday")

DOW.Sunday == 1  # True
DOW(1)  # <DOW.Sunday: 1>
```